# Where is "View Call Hierarchy" in universal windows development?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp, call-hierarchy

In the `Call Hierarchy` window, Visual Studio is telling me to right click and select `View Call Hierarchy` to show the call hierarchy.

I can't seem to find this option, not when running and not when paused on a breakpoint in a relevant context.

Here is an image of what I see in my right-click menu (I have resharper installed):

[image]

When I use the key combination Ctrl+K T, Visual Studio notifies me that `The key combination (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+T) is bound to command (View Call Hierarchy) which is not currently available`.

Any ideas?

Comment: For me it works fine in VS2012+Resharper and VS2015 without Resharper (we don't have Resharper yet for 2015).  With and without debugging.

Comment: @MartijnvandenH: are you doing universal windows development?

Comment: Ah sorry, read over that little detail. I'm not doing universal windows development.